# Python: Replace multiple strings with multiple strings in files

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm building a lab for a network certification.
There is some configurations for 13 devices, but since I don't got the exact same devices as the material was made for, I have to make some changes in the configurations.

I've tried to make a Python script, but it doesn't match exactly what I need.

I have a file with the changes to be made in the form:

find-this,replace-with-this
Now the configuration I have to change is primarily intarfaces, so it looks something like this (I have removed some configuration tom make it smaller):

```
interface Serial0
description Connected to R1
frame-relay route 102 interface Serial1 201
frame-relay route 103 interface Serial2 301
frame-relay route 104 interface Serial4 401
frame-relay route 105 interface Serial5 501
frame-relay route 113 interface Serial3 311
!
interface Serial1
description Connected to R2
frame-relay route 201 interface Serial0 102
frame-relay route 203 interface Serial2 302
frame-relay route 204 interface Serial4 402
frame-relay route 205 interface Serial5 502
frame-relay route 213 interface Serial3 312
!
```

Where I want to replace

```
Serial0,Serial1/0
Serial1,Serial1/1
Serial2,Serial1/2
Serial3,Serial1/3
Serial4,Serial1/4
```

Or like this:

```
interface Serial0/0
!
interface Serial0/0.1 point-to-point
!
interface Serial0/1
!
```

Where I want to replace

```
Serial0/0,Serial0/2/0
Serial0/1,Serial0/1/0
```

Right now I do it line by line with this method:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = re.sub("\\b"+i+"\\b", j, text)
```

My problem is that Serial0 or Serial0/0 gets matched the first time and changed to Serial1/0, but this is then matched by the Serial1 so I get Serial1/1/0.
I've tried with both boundry (\b) and ^ and $ but it doesn't seem to work; also I have the case where its okey to be Serial1 but not Serial1/0, but it's okey with Serial1.200.

So it should match exactly what I want to find, or exactly what I want to find + a dot and some numbers eg. Serial0/1.200

Anyone knows how to do this and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process line by line and break the loop:

```
new_text=""
for line in lines:
    new_text= new_text + fix_line(line)

def fix_line(line):
     for i, j in dic.iteritems():
          new_line = re.sub("\\b"+i+"\\b", j, line)
          if new_line != line: #line changed stop loop
               return new_line
     return line #line didn't match

print(new_text)
```

**edit**: if you want an exact match on the regex you should use split

```
 str_list = line.split(" ")
 if len(str_list) > 4: #case the line has interface
     process(str_list[4])

 def process(str_to_match):
     if str_to_match in dic:
           return dic[str_to_match] #will get the exact match saved in the dict
     return str_to_match #not in dict dont replace
```

Answer (score 0):

An inefficient but effective way might be to manually do a while loop like a for loop through the code, checking the string in front of the position variable against your word list then replacing if there is a hit, and adding the length of the replacement word to the position variable. A bit ugly but easy and effective.